# Making a flashcard in html and css

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm having a little issue creating a flashcard. When there is no text, the lines of the flashcard are correctly positioned, but when I add text, the lines get pushed down below the text and below the boundaries of the flashcard.
Setting a `z-index` didn't fix this issue.
Any advice?

```css
.container {

    display: flex;
    width: 1280px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}


#flashcards {
    width: 38vw;
    height: 40vh;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}


.redline{
    width: 38vw;
    height: 40vh;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
    height: 1px;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
}

.blueline {
    width: 38vw;
    height: 40vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);
    height: 1px;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
}

#welcome {
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    font-size: 3.3em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="flashcards" class="flashcard">
      <p id="welcome">Welcome <br> Sign in or create an account</p>
      <hr class="redline">
      <hr class="blueline">
      <hr class="blueline">
      <hr class="blueline">
      <hr class="blueline">
      <hr class="blueline">
      <hr class="blueline">
      <hr class="blueline">
      <hr class="blueline">
      <hr class="blueline">
      <hr class="blueline">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updated
you have given new requirements:

This worked for me. first change the #welcome position to fixed. next I change the 'p' tag to a "div" tag.

Please view the sample code in full page mode:)
if you want it to work with out using the full page option change: font-size: 3.3em; to font-size: 1.3em;

your code
[image: your code]

my code
[image: My code]

Update
[image]

```html
<style>
    .container {

        display: flex;
        width: 1280px;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    
    
    #flashcards {
        width: 38vw;
        height: 40vh;
        margin: auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background-color: white;
        padding-top: 25px;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    }
    
    
    .redline{
        width: 38vw;
        height: 40vh;
        background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
        height: 1px;
        z-index: 5;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .blueline {
        width: 38vw;
        height: 40vh;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);
        height: 1px;
        z-index: 5;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    #welcome {
        z-index: 10;
        position: fixed;
        top: 150px;
        font-size: 3.3em;
    }
</style>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        
      <div id="flashcards" class="flashcard">
        <div id="welcome">Welcome <br> Sign in or create an account</div>

        <hr class="redline">
        <hr class="blueline">
        <hr class="blueline">
        <hr class="blueline">
        <hr class="blueline">
        <hr class="blueline">
        <hr class="blueline">
        <hr class="blueline">
        <hr class="blueline">
        <hr class="blueline">
        <hr class="blueline">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: This did not work when i tried it.

Comment: it works in full page mode man

Comment: add image of it working full page:)

Comment: if you want it to work with out using the full page option change: font-size: 3.3em; tooo font-size: 1.3em;

Comment: Sorry. There was some confusing.  I didn't specify. I was wanting it to look like an actual flashcard with the lines going almost all the way to the top and the text laying on top of the lines.

Comment: Okay that's it. Thank you.